# Matrix Representation of Convolution in Neural Networks: Challenges in Backpropagation and Parameter Updates

Tags: conv-neural-network, matrix-multiplication, backpropagation

In neural networks, convolution operations are typically performed using a filter (or kernel) that slides over the input data and computes dot products at each location to produce the output feature map. These operations are generally implemented as element-wise multiplications and summations rather than explicit matrix multiplications. However, it's possible to [write a convolution operation as a matrix multiplication](https://github.com/alisaaalehi/convolution_as_multiplication/blob/main/ConvAsMulExplained.pdf) of the input signal with a doubly circular matrix based on the kernel (for one input channel and one output channel).

Can we update convolution layers (e.g., via backprop) when writing them in the doubly circular matrix form? My understanding is that different blocks of the resulting matrix correspond to different parts of the input, and updating them would not correspond to a valid convolution operation.